# Go to specific Image in UIScroll View

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an UIScroll View to display Images and I'm using the Scroll View Example from apple.
I wanted to add a thumbnail view from an another Example called AutoScroller.
(I put the links at the end of the post.)

So i figured out to add the thumbnail bar, but I want to change the current image in the Scroll View to the one I select at the thumbnail bar.

Any Idea?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the position of your of your image you want to scroll to and call `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` on your `UIScrollView` to go to this position.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but is there no other method to do this? Because I have many images and getting the position of every Image would be very difficult.

Comment: No other method to do this. Each of your image is displayed in an UIImageView, you can just get the frame property to know the position of your image in the scrollView?

Answer (score 0):

In this way i am setting scrollview content offset when click on any button just use sender.tag of button and [frameScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320*sender.tag, 0)];

if you not understand this then i can send you full code

- (IBAction) nextFrameButtonClicked {

  if (frameScrollView.contentOffset.x  >= 230*9 ) {

//[frameScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(frameScrollView.contentOffset.x-230, 0)];

}else {

[frameScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(frameScrollView.contentOffset.x+230, 0)];

```
}
```

}

- (IBAction) prevFrameButtonClicked {

if (frameScrollView.contentOffset.x  <=0 ) {

//[frameScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(frameScrollView.contentOffset.x+230, 0)];

}else {
[frameScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(frameScrollView.contentOffset.x-230, 0)];

```
}
```

}